# Rails 4.2 app: selenium update after Firefox 55 upgrade breaks tests: fails to click_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a legacy rails application currently running on rails 4.2. It has been running correctly under test using selenium-webdriver 2.53.4 and Firefox 47.0.1. I need to upgrade Firefox to the latest version (55.0.3). As a consequence I also need to update selenium to 3.4.x or later. In doing so tests now fail.

I have tried many combinations of cucumber, cucumber-rails, capybara, and selenium-webdriver with geckodriver 0.19.

The known to work before combo:

cucumber 1.3.20
cucumber-rails 1.4.3
capybara 2.3.0
selenium-webdriver: 2.53.4

(note that using this config with just selenium-webdriver updated showed the same behavior in test failure)

The latest attempt which is still failing:

cucumber 2.3.3
cucumber-rails 1.4.5
capybara 2.15.1
selenium-webdriver: 3.4.4 or 3.5.2

The behavior: all the cucumber tests that fail seem to have one thing in common. They page.click_link on a link in the web page, the click_link action returns {} to the cucumber step rather than throw any exception, and the page from the link is then never loaded. I can put in 10 second delays and nothing happens. I cannot see why this would be the case. What ends up happening is the next cucumber step fails because the expected page is not loaded.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've googled quite a bit and get lots of hits regarding capybara and click_link but none describe my situation. Thanks for feedback.

```
Given(/\As?he clicks on the link labeled "([^"]+)"\z/) do |name|
page.click_link name
end
```

Comment: Capybara's `click_link` (in version 2.15.1) returns the element it clicked, so if it's returning `{}` then it's not actually calling Capybara's `click_link` - have you overridden `click_link` for some reason?  Use a debugger and step into it and see what it's actually calling

Comment: My comment about returning {} was indeed referencing an earlier version of capybara. With 2.15.1 it does return the clicked link: (#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/a">). I verified that we have not overridden click_link and think had we then the tests would have failed before the selenium webdriver update. Stepped in with the debugger and it returns success.

Comment: What version of geckodriver are you using?

Comment: Using version 0.19.0 of geckodriver.

Comment: One more thing -- What are you using as your driver registration/selenium config?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no driver registration configuration. So that should default to :selenium I think.

Comment: Ok -- that should rule out configuration issues then, are the links just plain links, or do they have JS behavior attached to them?

Comment: I suspect the issue is related to JS. The link has three classes: "large green button". Removing the "button" class makes the problem go away.

Comment: I removed all javascript from the code and the problem still manifested itself. Looking at the "button" class CSS there was a .button:active style definition that had position: relative and top: 1px;. Removing the position: relative setting allowed the tests to pass. Pretty weird. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the CSS was moving the link after its position was already calculated or something - weird. Anyway glad its working for you now.